# Firestore query adding same data on document change - Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm using this method to load active users:

```
private void loadActiveUsers() {

    usersList.clear();

    Query activeUsersQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("active", true);
    activeUsersQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            for (DocumentChange documentChange: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                    String user_id = documentChange.getDocument().getId();
                    Users users = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Users.class).withId(user_id);
                    usersList.add(users);

                    activeUsersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED) {

                    String user_id = documentChange.getDocument().getId();
                    Users users = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Users.class).withId(user_id);
                    usersList.remove(users);
                    usersList.clear();
                    usersList.add(users);

                    activeUsersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED) {

                    String user_id = documentChange.getDocument().getId();
                    Users users = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Users.class).withId(user_id);
                    usersList.remove(users);

                    activeUsersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

        }
    });

}
```

When a new user becomes active, his name is added to the list but multiple times. When the refresh button is clicked, the list is back to normal. And if he is inactive, the recyclerview is messed up.

This is the adapter:

```
public class ActiveUsersRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActiveUsersRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public List<Users> usersList;
public Context context;

public ActiveUsersRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Users> usersList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.usersList = usersList;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_list_item, parent, false);
    context = parent.getContext();
    return new ViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final String userID = usersList.get(position).UserID;

    String image = usersList.get(position).getImage();
    holder.setImage(image);

    String username = usersList.get(position).getUsername();
    holder.setUsername(username);

    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(context, userID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return usersList.size();

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View view;

    public CircleImageView imageView;
    public TextView usernameView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        view = itemView;

    }

    public void setImage(String image) {

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_image);
        Glide.with(context).load(image).into(imageView);

    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {

        usernameView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_username);
        usernameView.setText(username);

    }

}
```

}

I tried the `holder.setIsRecyclable(false)` but it didn't work.

How can I prevent the data from being added multiple times or prevent the recycler from messing up?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance? Did you already step through `onEvent` in a debugger to see if it behaves as you'd expect? How often do you call `loadActiveUsers`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen its is called when activity is started and when the refresh button is clicked

Comment: That would explain then. Since you're adding a listener with `addSnapshotListener` it will stay active after you attach it. You don't need to recall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `addSnapshotListener` you're adding a permanent listener to the data. When you attach the listener it immediately starts loading the data and calls your `onEvent`, but it also stays actively monitoring the data and calls `onEvent` again if there's any relevant change (such as when another user becomes active). So if you use `addSnapshotListener` there's no need to call `loadActiveUsers` multiple times.

If you only want to load the active users when you call `loadActiveUsers`, consider using the `get()` method instead. When you call `get()` the data is only loaded that once single time. So in that case, you can recall `loadActiveUsers` whenever the user hits refresh to load the updated data.

In general I'd recommend using `addSnapshotListener` though, as it makes your UI be responsive to changes in the data (no matter where they originate from). But in that case be sure to only attach the listener once (typically when you create the activity) and remove it when you're done (typically when the activity is stopped, paused or hidden).

Comment: But if a username becomes inactive the list doesn't refresh. Or if he is active again the item is duplicated.  And do you have any idea how can I order the query by username?

Comment: If you use `addSnapshotListener` and a user becomes inactive, the `onEvent` will fire with a `DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED` for that document.